# laradock Modify the PHP configuration file to make it work at workspace

Tags: php, laravel, laradock

1. I modified the php7.1.ini file to add `phar. Readonly = off`
2. use `docker-compose restart php-fpm`
3. use `docker-compose exec workspace bash`
4. use `php xxx phar` is error

```
error info:
disabled by the php.ini setting phar.readonly
```

How can I get PHP to configure workspace to work?
tks.

Comment: you need to do a build to consider file modifications: docker-compose build php-fpm

Answer (score 1):

Which file exactly did you change?

Connect to your workspace and run:

```
php --ini
```

Then, copy the 'Loaded Configuration File' path and run (remember to change the path if yours is different):

```
cat /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini | grep -n phar.readonly


laradock@901e2daa988c:/var/www$ cat /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini | grep -n 
phar.readonly
1057:; http://php.net/phar.readonly
1058:;phar.readonly = On
```

It'll probably show that it's ON and the line number. So, just vim into the file and edit and set it to off (remember to change the line number, mine is 1058):

```
vim +1058 /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini
```

Comment: Why my php.ini file in workspace have this path.
laradock@b37c0fe38ffe:/var/www$ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php/7.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini

But in phpinfo() 
https://i.imgur.com/p9z1Tzj.png